# How to continue the for loop for next query even the previous query has error?

Tags: vb.net

This is a VB.NET coding for extract a set of databases from 100 of databases with the field **"flag"**.
I want to execute this select query in all databases containing in **"dbs"** arraylist.

```
For i = 0 To dbs.Count
    Sql = " select company, branch, year, flag from " + dbs(i) + ".global"
    
    Try
        With Cmd
            .CommandText = Sql
            .Connection = MyCnn
        End With
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        ' do nothing
    End Try

    Dim reader1 As MySqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If (reader1("flag").ToString() = "10") Then
        MyDbList.Company = reader1("company")
        MyDbList.Branch = reader1("branch")
        MyDbList.Year = reader1("year")
        MyDbList.DbName = reader("Database")
    End If
```

Comment: What is the point of your `Try...Catch` block? There's no code in there that could possibly throw an exception. Maybe you should put the code that could actually throw an exception inside the `Try` block.

Comment: You also might consider closing your data reader. Maybe you already are and you just haven't shown it. If not, do so.

Comment: Your For loop is going to go beyond the end of  dbs. It should be `For i = 0 To dbs.Count - 1`

Comment: What is `MyDbList`? Where does `reader` come from? Is this code working? If not what errors are you getting? Are you connecting directly to the server instead of an individual database? Is the connection successful? Is global a table name in each of the databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort the current iteration of a loop and go straight onto the next one then you can use the `Continue` keyword. Assuming that you actually write a sensible exception handler, you can put `Continue For` in the `Catch` block.

Comment: The [MS doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/continue-statement) on `Continue [Do|For|While]` is quite clear.

Comment: @SteveCinq, I'm not sure whether you're trying to imply something by that comment or you're just informing us that the documentation is clear, which seems somewhat superfluous.

Comment: I'm providing a reference link to the explanatory doco. Not superfluous, nothing "implied". (Are you implying that I'm implying something?)

Comment: @SteveCinq, I was inquiring whether I should infer an implication. Crisis averted.

Comment: Whew! Too close for comfort.

Comment: First of all Thanks !  But it doesn't works !

Comment: Yes it does. If what you did failed then it's because you did it wrong. You should update your question with the new code and a description of its behaviour, both expected and actual, and then add a comment to indicate that the question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @jmcilhinney has implied, this should work ...

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dbs.Count - 1
    Try
        Sql = $"select company, branch, year, flag from {dbs(i)}.global"

        With Cmd
            .CommandText = Sql
            .Connection = MyCnn
        End With

        Using reader1 As MySqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If (reader1("flag").ToString() = "10") Then
                With MyDbList
                    .Company = reader1("company")
                    .Branch = reader1("branch")
                    .Year = reader1("year")
                    .DbName = reader1("database")
                End With
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As MySqlException ' Other exception types won't be caught by this Catch!
        ' Maybe log something somewhere?
        Continue For
    End Try
Next i
```

Note use of `Using` and string interpolation and correction to `For` loop range as per @Mary's comment. As always, turn `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` on - and, IMHO, `Option Infer` off - to highlight any compilation issues.

Finally, to be clear, this isn't how I would code this up; I'm only trying to address your question here.

Comment: See my comment to the OP.

Comment: @Mary Agreed, and corrected. Personally I'd probably go for a `For Each` if possible in this scenario.

Comment: This never calls `reader.Read()`, which means the first row is never loaded.

Comment: Thank a Lot Mr.Steve !

Comment: @MariappanGnanaraj No problem. Feel free to up-vote and/or mark as answered.